# mustache template function call not working

Tags: jquery, mustache

Trying to do a function call with mustache getting Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function. No idea what's wrong documentation sucks. Want it to display instead of the rating an image in the search bar.

http://jsfiddle.net/JhsmB/

```
$('#search-fld').typeahead([{                              
    name: 'best-picture-winners',
    local: 
[
  {
    "year": "1961",
    "value": "West Side Story",
    "rating": "PG13",
    "wrapped": function () { return function (text, render) {
       return "<img src=" + render(text) + ".jpg>";
    }
  },
    "tokens": [
      "West",
      "Side",
      "Story"
    ]
  },
  {
    "year": "1962",
    "value": "Lawrence of Arabia",
     "rating": "PG",
    "wrapped": function () { return function (text, render) {
      return "<img src=" + render(text) + ".jpg>";
    }
  },
    "tokens": [
      "Lawrence",
      "of",
      "Arabia"
    ]
  },
  {
    "year": "1963",
    "value": "Tom Jones",
    "rating": "R",
     "wrapped": function () { return function (text, render) {
       return "<img src=" + render(text) + ".jpg>";
    }
  },
    "tokens": [
      "Tom",
      "Jones"
    ]
  }
],

template: '<p><strong>{{value}}</strong> – ({{year}} -  {{#wrapped}}{{rating}}{{/wrapped}}',                                                                 
engine: Hogan                                                         
}]);
```

Comment: what is render ? Any definition for render ? console error: render is not a function. Also what is text argument passed to the function.

Comment: @maheshSapkal it's part of the mustache templating engine, http://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html , i don't know why it's not working

Comment: OK cool, what's the name of the image file ?

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I think render doesn't work with Hogan.js. I've updated the local (datums). Also the datum was incorrect. I've updated wrapper and template as well.

Hope this helps. :)

```
$('#search-fld').typeahead([{
    name: 'best-picture-winners',
    local: [{
      "year": "1961",
      "value": "West Side Story",
      "rating": "PG13",
      "wrapped": function () { 
        return "<img src=" + this.rating + ".jpg/>";
      },
      "tokens": ["West","Side","Story"]
    },
    {
      "year": "1962",
      "value": "Lawrence of Arabia",
      "rating": "PG",
      "wrapped": function () { 
          return "<img src=" + this.rating + ".jpg/>";
      },
      "tokens": ["Lawrence","of","Arabia"]
    },
    {
      "year": "1963",
      "value": "Tom Jones",
      "rating": "R",
      "wrapped": function () { 
          return "<img src=" + this.rating + ".jpg/>";
      },
      "tokens": ["Tom","Jones"]
    }
  ],
  template: '<p><strong>{{value}}</strong> – ({{year}} -  {{{wrapped}}})',
  engine: Hogan
}]);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JhsmB/3/)**

Comment: ok let me try this with my remote source and if it works ill love you forever